# Maximum value of angular momentum component in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

Since $[L^2, L_z]=0$, we can say that they share a common eigenbasis, call it $f$, and $L^2f=\lambda f$, $L_z f=\mu f$

The ladder operators for the $z$ component of angular momentum are

$$L_\pm=L_x\pm iL_y$$

Applying the ladder operator to eigenfunction, $f$, we get

$$L_z(L_\pm f)=(\mu\pm\hbar)(L_\pm f) \tag1$$

At this point, most authors say that there must be some eigenfunction, $f_t$ which has the property

$$L_+ft=0\tag2$$

Otherwise, by continuously raising we would get $\langle L_z\rangle >\langle L\rangle$.

This implies by (1) that the $z$ component of angular momentum of that state is zero.

But why make the RHS of (2) zero? Why can't we say that $L_+f_t=f_t$? Making it so that $L_z$ of all the states above $f_t$ have same value as $f_t$.

Edit: *A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics, Second Edition* by John S. Townsend has a very nice alternative reasoning. Essentially he argues that the fact that the expectation value of $L_x^2+L_y^2$ has to be greater than zero, it follows that (2) must be true.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The authors seem to state that $(2)$ holds. And you ask why they don't state something else?!

Comment: @TobiasFünke I made my concern clear now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear to me. Do you want a prove that $(2)$ holds? Or what? What do you mean with "make the RHS of $(2)$ zero? The statement is (seems to be; consider to give a reference): There exists some vector $f$ such that $L_+f=0$.

Comment: @TobiasFünke As i said that $L_z$ of a state greater than $f_t$ is zero. But why? Why can't we say that $L_z$ of the states greater than $f_t$ are $L$?

Comment: You suggestion would likely cause the operators to violate the commutation relations, because we *used* the commutation relations to show that $J_+$ necessarily increases the eigenvalue.

Comment: As march says, if $L_+ f_t = f_t$ then $f_t$ is an eigenstate of $L_+$ and your equation (1) does not hold anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not consistent with the algebra.

$f_t$ is an eigenstate of $L_z$ with some eigenvalue $\mu$. You have shown that the state $L_+ f_t$ has eigenvalue $\mu + \hbar$. How, then, can $L_+ f_t$ be the same as $f_t$?